# Prove there's no holomorphic function $f$ defined in $B(0,2)$ such that ${{(-1)^n}\over{n}} + e^{f({{1}\over{n}})}=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't fully understand the proposed solution based on the identity theorem. We end up getting  $z+e^{f(z)}=1$ and $-z+e^{f(z)}=1$ which is a contradiction.

I would like some help to understand how we get there and the reasoning behind.

Thank you!

Comment: It's the identity theorem. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I am.

Answer (score 6):

The point is to split up the conditions into odd and even $n$. If such an $f$ existed, it would certainly satisfy

$$1 = \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k+1} + e^{f\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)} = -\frac{1}{2k+1} + e^{f\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)}.$$

Since $\bigl\{ \frac{1}{2k+1} : k\in\mathbb{N}\bigr\}$ has $0$ as an accumulation point, the identity theorem tells us that $f$ then satisfies

$$-z + e^{f(z)} = 1,$$

or that $f$ is a branch of $\log (1+z)$.

Similarly, $\bigl\{ \frac{1}{2k} : k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\bigr\}$ has $0$ as an accumulation point, so from

$$1 = \frac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k}  + e^{f\left(\frac{1}{2k}\right)} = \frac{1}{2k}  + e^{f\left(\frac{1}{2k}\right)}$$

we deduce that $f$ satisfies

$$z + e^{f(z)} = 1,$$

or that $f$ is a branch of $\log (1-z)$.

Since $1+z$ and $1-z$ are different functions, $f$ cannot be simultaneously be a branch of both, $\log (1+z)$ and $\log (1-z)$.